# seleniumでのxpathのループ

Tags: selenium

seleniumを使用してスクレイピングをしたいと考えています。
下記のコードを実行するとxpathの部分のテキストが表示されます。

```
elem_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
elem_username[0].text
```

**わからないこと：xpathのループの仕方がわからない**

xpathの数字を変えて同じ階層にあるものをループで取得するにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
そもそもxpathは変数を入れることができるのでしょうか？下のコードのようにxpathの一部をiに変えても
うまくいきません。

```
i = 1
elem_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[i]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
elem_username[i-1].text
```

**エラー内容**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-ce74f60583df> in <module>
      1 i = 1
      2 elem_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[i]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
----> 3 elem_username[i-1].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

非常に初歩的な内容かもしれませんが教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: `'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[i]/...'` とした場合、これは文字列になります。つまり、`div[i]` の `i` は `i` という文字そのものとして扱われます。Python 3.6 以降には f-string という文字列リテラルが導入されていて文字列中で変数の値を展開することができます。この場合は `elem_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')` とします。

Comment: 実行することができました。助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: metropolisさんへ 　回答は回答欄に書かれた方が良いのではないでしょうか？
質問者さんへ　解決されたようなので解決済にしてください。。